# What is the purpose of having a temple?

Tags: temple

The answer I am looking for is more from a perspective of "What was the original purpose for which people used temples" how has it changed and has it changed for the worse or for the good.

Any citation to literature would be preferred, but I am looking for opinions from people who have had this thought in some form.

I did have a look at ([What do Hindu scriptures say about Hindu temples?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/what-does-hindu-scriptures-say-about-hindu-temples)), but I guess these are different in the purpose, I am primarily looking for what people feel was the purpose of it and most importantly the modern day purpose and its repercussions on the way Hinduism is perceived both by Hindus and others.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate of http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3650/36, but I'll let others weigh in.

Comment: one potential purpose of having a temple is to have a place where people from the community come and pray together. Analogy: we can watch cricket match from our house on TV. we can also watch cricket in the stadium. However the stadium provides a better experience because of the fact that there is large crowd of supporters with energy throughout the cricket show. Similarly instead of praying at one's home all the time, if every week a group of people get together and sing the glory of the Lord/chant hymns in praise, the energy thus generated recharges us filling us with His blessings Sir.

Comment: @Sai I dont see any reason why your comment cannot be an answer

Answer (score 3):

Temple plays important roles in our Hindu culture. Past temples objective was absolutely classical and logical. But, Today I am not sure about this.

In the morning and evening, all village or town people gathered in one place and that place was a temple.

In my village temples were used as divine commercial banks says by my grandfather. How?

Note: Here, I am talking about my village temple.

All people are gathered here and discuss their lives and problem happily. Everyone contributes some money according to their capacity in temple donation box.

That collected money gives to needed person incognito. So, he can't feel minority. When he will able to capable then he gives the money back and completes the cycles.

**Other things are that we believe that wind is everywhere but when we need some rest or feel hot at that time we go to the under the fan. Same thing we believe in a spiritual world like we know that God is everywhere but get relaxation we go to the temple and feel free.**

Comment: While I appreciate your answer, and the previous answer, I dont think it answers my real question, which can be pharaphrased as what do you believe should be the real purpose of going to a temple, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Temples were the earliest places for social gathering.  Morning Prayers, evening prayers and they help people gather and discuss their problems and thoughts(Speaking for the earliest reason).

Bigger Temples were used by kings to hide their Gold assets(Kerala's padmanabh temple).

They were means to display there connection of king with god(Temples created by Raja Raja Cholan).

Kings always try to display that they are supported by GOD to rule. Be it indian kings, romans, or egyptian.