# Can a building be constructed over a temple?

Tags: temple

My question is whether a building (with rooms and bathrooms), for residential/commercial use can be built over an existing temple.

Such a building is under construction at Jaipur.

Is it permissible?

Comment: Tag suggestion: "vastu-shastra"

Comment: Permissible by local law or permissible by Hindu scriptures? Please clarify your question. Also, see a related question here: [What does Hindu scriptures say about Hindu temples?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/what-does-hindu-scriptures-say-about-hindu-temples)

Comment: It is not permitted by scripture. In fact even surrounding buildings must not be taller than the temple and the dwaja stambha serves this purpose inter alia. Let us ask ourselves this. Is it acceptable to have bathrooms above the temple, which the complex surely will have? Certainly not.

Comment: My experience is that those that do build, do not have anything built over the inner shrine, or if built over the inner shrine, the space immediately above the inner shrine is left empty. Are they building over the inner shrine or just over other portions of the temple?