# Who owns a Hindu temple according to Hindu scriptures?

Tags: scripture, temple, priests

Subramanian Swamy said in a video that God owns the temple, and the pundit only acts as a 'trustee'. Is this validated by the *Hindu* scriptures? Also, assuming it is validated, is this applicable to all Hindu temples?

Can a private person, a private group, or a public entity like a government not own a temple?

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/what-do-hindu-scriptures-say-about-hindu-temples) question discusses various other aspects of a temple without going into property rights.

Answer (score 4):

A temple is among few such places that does not have any owner. This is according to Usana Smriti.
So, Mr Swami is right with what he said.

> Forests, mountains, **sacred shrines**, sacrificial places,
> **all these are described as having no owners. No one has any right of possession over them.** (16)
>
> **Usana Smriti (or Samhita); Chapter 5; Verse 16**

Comment: Just asking, there were Vanavasis who lived in Forests and Mountains and Sastras recommend them to live so, so if Kings or any others enter they will have to pay tax to them and take resources of forests by paying them right

Comment: Did not understand your question. Who are required to pay taxes to whom?@SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: The people who come to forests and buy things from it to the vanavasis

Comment: As shown by the verse forest resources belong to God. So I don't understand why pay taxes to the Vanavasis. The Vanavasis don't own the forest resources. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Then how do they own money Dont they sell honey, lac etc all

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: How can the Vanavasis earn money ..Cant they sell the forest products to the citizens

Comment: Yes they do that but the forest resources don't belong to them. That's my point. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: I see. But citizens cant go take it for free right? they should purchase from the Vanavasis right?

Comment: How can citizens get ready made honey? There are some people who fetch the honey and make it suitable for our consumption. If the citizens learn this method then they can themselves directly get honey without paying a third party money. But it doesn't work like that. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: I see. But then how can these Vanavasis make money?Without selling fruits honey n so on? May be they grow and control something and find a way to earn money?

Comment: Really sorry for asking stupid qns