# Who maintains temples according to scriptures?

Tags: scripture, temple

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40999/661) answer says that temples are not owned by any one. But, do scriptures mention anything about a maintainer?

Is it king? Is it a person from a particular lineage? or other?

Maintainer can be viewed as a person who either performs all the activities for the temple or who controls the former or both.

Comment: temples - buildings in which worship is conducted - are a fairly recent development when you consider how old Hinduism is. Scriptures do speak of personages, conducting worship, etc, etc., but not of buildings