# Why is it required to visit a Temple?

Tags: temple

Visiting temples on auspicious days, festivals and even on a daily basis is one of the habits that almost every Hindu has and for that case any human being (based on their religion), visits an appropriate devotional place! This is one such belief that is enforced by most of the Parents on their children saying that it helps you be connected with the God!

My question is why is it required to visit a temple to be connected with God?

What are the benefits that one gets by visiting temples?

You can still be connected with God, even without visiting a temple. Please do not reply with answers saying that visiting a temple will imbibe positive energy or rejuvenates all your senses or helps you connect with God better than at home. The hypothetical theory that gives this explanation holds good to temples that were built earlier with all the Vaastu and accoustics in consideration. Now-a-days there is a temple or a devotional place on every street.

You can still be connected with God staying anywhere, as the presence of God is said to be existent everywhere!

Comment: If you regularly do nitya karma there is no need to visit temple you meditate on Bramhan directly by doing Nitya-karma like Sandhyavandana. Temples are for those who are unable/not-eligible to do their nitya karma because they can only have darshan of Shriman Narayan/Bramhan in temples.

Comment: Related [What do Hindu scriptures say about Hindu temples?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3650/3500)

Comment: You can justify in both ways... if you think going to temple does some good like positive vibrations... then you can justify many benefits of going temples citing Puranas... if you think it is not necessary to go to temple as God is omnipresent.. then also you can justify your points by citing Vedas... as Vedas do not mention of any temples nor visiting them.. you can just realize Brahman sitting in a room through Upanishads... or you can meditate on Brahma Vidyas... however it can't be justified that going temple is wrong...