# What is the oldest scripture which explains how a temple should be built?

Tags: scripture, history, temple, translation-request, india

What is the oldest (surviving) Hindu scripture which explains how a temple should be built, maintained, and what should be its day-to-day affairs?

Is an English translation of the same available?

Is the same scripture followed even today if someone wants to build a new temple?

---

Note: This is not a dup. of *[What do Hindu scriptures say about Hindu temples?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/what-do-hindu-scriptures-say-about-hindu-temples)* which looks too broad and should probably be closed. This question is specific to scriptures explaining how a temple should be constructed/maintained/run.

Comment: "How a temple should be built" -  Are you looking for the info of what/how should be the Vastu of the temple like? or anything else?

Comment: see the wikipedia article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_temple

Comment: @Rickross Yes, the scripture which explains the architecture of the temple, its purpose, how it should be operated, etc.

Comment: @sv. Okay........

Comment: Many chapters from Agni Purana before or after [this chapter](https://archive.org/stream/AgniPuranaChowkhambaSurbharati/Agni%20Purana%20-%20Chowkhamba%20Surbharati#page/n97/mode/1up) may be useful...

Comment: @YDS Is it talking about installation of idol or how to build the temple itself?

Comment: @sv. It has details of how to build temple also...but u need to go through many chapters...